# Create Advanced Reporting - Moodle

Tags: php, reporting, moodle

I am really a newbie to Moodle and I have got this advanced functionality to build for a client's Moodle site as quickly as I can. I have been reading a lot about Moodle through its documentation and any other online resources I can found but thought of taking some help from the experts out here too.

I am looking forward to build an advanced reporting feature where different role users have the permissions to view advanced reports (high level, overview level, individual)down their hierarchy.

The report data would be based on organization hierarchy i.e. say a manager can view a department report, within a dept he can select any of the sections, within a section, he can select any area and eventually any individual within that area.

I need to write a separate plugin for this so that future upgrades don't over ride the changes. Can any one give me a starting point as to how to go about this one? Any links, pointers or suggestions would be useful as I am totally new with Moodle right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put this plugin in the /local folder and provide access to its pages via links added to the main navigation block. This is done by putting the following function into /local/myplugin/lib.php which will be picked up automatically:

```
myplugin_extends_navigation(global_navigation $navigation) {
    // Read the docs for get_context_instance and look at other uses to see what params you need
    $usercontext = get_context_instance(CONTEXT_USER, $USER->id, MUST_EXIST);

    // You will need to define some capabilities or use existing ones. If the user is allowed, they see the link below
    if (has_capability('whatevercapability', $context)) {

        // Adds a link
        $node_schedule = $nodecoursework->add('Submission Schedule',
                                              new moodle_url('/local/myplugin/sub.php'),
                                              navigation_node::TYPE_CUSTOM,
                                              'Submission Schedule',
                                              'Submission Schedule');
    }
}
```

The report pages are then placed in the folder as separate files (sub.php in this example). Look for the html_table() class to make the report, also its sql-based subclasses.

Docs for making a local plugin are [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins) and you can see an example [here](https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-local_codechecker).

Comment: Oh thanks for your reply. Well I hv strted building modules first for a hierarchy creation where ppl can create new departments, sections n areas and assign it to each other. Then finaly put users into dis logical groups.I'm doin dis by creatin a plugin cald user hierarchy in /blocks/ folder and 1ce whn I hev my hierarchy ready I am gonna create a plugin in /report/ folder which wud take these hierarchies in to consideration n let diff level of users to view diff reports. Is dis way right as well? And probably there r too many complications ahead too bt mre o less im gonna do it this way.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, although /reports is non-standard, so a lot of the bits and pieces like picking up on navigation links, running unit tests etc won't scan it, which could be a disadvantage. How are you making the hierarchies? The roles/contexts system is supposed to provide those for you already.

Comment: Dint get u? what do u mean by roles/contexts system already provides that for you?As I had mentioned earlier, I have created a new plugin with tables for depts,sections, areas and a separate table which maps sections into departments and areas into sections. Now the bit that is left is to put users into these hierarchies and set permissions across them based on their hierarchy. Once this is done I'll start on my report plugin.

Comment: I mean that if you make a hierarchy of course categories and name them as depts, sections, areas etc. Then you can assign users roles e.g. teacher, student, department head (you can make up your own roles too and say what permissions they have) within those categories. Each category is a context that can have users in roles and also certain permissions overridden e.g. someone can be a teacher in dept A, but you have set it so that in that dept, teachers cannot mark essays, only view them.

Comment: You can also do that for individual users. Permissions are cascading, so a teacher in dept A will also be a teacher in all sections and areas below it unless you override their role in a lower context. More info here http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Assign_roles Assuming you're on 2.x, check out the Site administration -> users -> permissions -> define roles, also make hierarchical categories in Site administration -> courses ->add/edit courses, then click on one and look for Settings ->assign roles in the block at the side. I very strongly recommend using this system and not reinventing the wheel

Comment: Well I think I'll have to make these hierarchies through some sort of plugin. Because categories would not allow each of them to be a part of each other. Like say I have 3 different departments, each of those departments have, say 2 sections each, and each of those sections have 3 areas each. Eventually these areas will have members under them. Will your categories idea help me create such a hierarchical structure? Also I do not want that say if a teacher is made the head of one department, she is also the head of the sections and the areas.This defeats my purpose of creating the report plugin

Comment: My report for which in the first place I started making this hierarchy creation plugin requires such kind of hierarchy. Since my Moodle site is for a large organisations who would want to teach and train their staff about different courses. It has to have departments>>sections>>area>>staff structure. And having a unique head/incharge for each dept/section/area will help them view the right kind of report. Like a manager of a department can only view his dept report and select a section or area within his report to view report further down.

Comment: Similarly a section head shud b able to view reports further down his hierarchy.i.e. report fr his section and areas within his section and so on.Hence I thut d best way to achieve this was to first create such a hierarchy tht maps areas into sections n sections into depts, then put users under such hierarchies and then which ever courses or learning activities is been taught is then viewed and assessed based on these hierarchies. Is there a better which could help me do all of these than the way I am doin right now. Cuz your way seems reasonable but I think may or may nt xactly do as I need.

Comment: The structure you've described is exactly the same as happens in every other school, university and company that teaches using Moodle. It's a problem that has already been solved since Moodle 1.7, and all bugs and use cases have been thoroughly worked through. It does all that you need and more. You just need to get your hands dirty in the docs :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7890/discussion-between-ivn-and-matt-gibson)